# What is the best way to create image from image filepath, modify pixel by pixel, then save in UWP app?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

What is the best way to create a bitmap image from file path, manipulate each pixel, and then save the image?

I have explored `WritableBitMap` in `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging` and the and WritableBitmapEx extension provided through Nuget However,

```
var displayPhoto = new WriteableBitmap(10, 10);
displayPhoto.SetSource(await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
var targetPixel = displayPhoto.GetPixel(x, t);
```

give me an error saying I want to access protected memory. Changing the file openmode to ReadWrite does not help, and gives me an error of "file is readonly", whereas I checked the property of the image file, write is enabled.

Comment: Look into your appmanafiest

Answer (score 0):

> give me an error saying I want to access protected memory.

The problem is your `WriteableBitmap` is too small to store all the data, For your requirement, you could create  `WriteableBitmap` with original image width and height.

```
var tem = new BitmapImage();
await tem.SetSourceAsync(await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read));

var displayPhoto = new WriteableBitmap(tem.PixelWidth, tem.PixelHeight);
displayPhoto.SetSource(await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read));
var targetPixel = displayPhoto.GetPixel(x,s);
```